# Invoice printing wrong data

Tags: html, database, vb.net, ado.net

I have a doubt in updating and printing in my project.

First i update data by using `ExecuteScalar` and getting Auto-Gen Number from Database

Then I'm Updating Invoice Number to another Table for Invoice numbering system

```
                TicketNumberUpdate()
                lbl_Status.Text = "Updating Ticket Number..."
                Application.DoEvents()
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
```

then wait to filter according to my Invoice number

```
  PrintFunc(" WHERE dbo.tbl_Tickets.TicketNo='" & txtTicket.Text & "' AND dbo.tbl_Tickets.Ticket_Type='" & cboTicketType.Text.Trim & "'")
                lbl_Status.Text = "Loading Ticket ..."
                Application.DoEvents()
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
```

and load that Invoice details to Richtextbox

```
                rtb_TicketFormat.Rtf = rtb_TicketFormat.Rtf.Replace("Duplicate.png", "Original.png")
                Dim myFileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(IO.Path.GetTempPath, "_.html")
                rtb_TicketFormat.SaveFile(myFileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

                lbl_Status.Text = "Printing Ticket ..."
                Application.DoEvents()
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
```

and wait for Save that Invoice in html format after that i call for `PrintTktz` for printing that file

```
Private Sub PrintTktz()

          Dim webBrowserForPrinting As New WebBrowser()

    AddHandler webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted, New  _
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PrintDocumentz)

    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = New Uri(IO.Path.GetTempPath & "_.html")

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocumentz(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim webBrowserForPrinting As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)
    webBrowserForPrinting.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

    webBrowserForPrinting.Print()


    webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose()



End Sub
```

Problem is that sometimes it prints previous Invoice not the current invoice does this code hangs? I am trying different methods to do this.

Comment: I would look into your temp file generation. Something is not being replaces there. Also, where you have `= CType(sender, WebBrowser)` do `= DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)`

Comment: i dont know file is generating when im testing without any problem, but sometimes i get this problem?