# SQL Server : duplicates value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm updating my project And now the problem is sometimes ticket number Duplicates after update whats wrong with this code?

Or what would be the most elegant solution to allow me to

My code is

```
DECLARE @tbl_ID TABLE (nID int)
UPDATE tbl_Tickets
SET Ticket_Type = @Ticket_Type,
VehicleNo= @VehicleNo,
Customer=@Customer,
Job_Code=@Job_Code,
Material=@Material,
First_Weight=@First_Weight,
Second_Weight=@Second_Weight,
Net_Weight=@Net_Weight,
Add_Charges=@Add_Charges,
Deduction=@Deduction,
Ticket_Amount=@Ticket_Amount,
SOURCE=@Source,
       Destination=@Destination,
OPERATOR=@Operator,
     Out_Time=@Out_Time,
     PC=@PC,
     Unit_Price=@Unit_Price OUTPUT INSERTED.QS_Code INTO @tbl_ID (nID)
 WHERE (VehicleNo=@VehicleNo)
 AND (Second_Weight IS NULL)
 AND (Ticket_Type <>'DELETED') IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 BEGIN

INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (Ticket_Type, TicketNo, VehicleNo, nDate, Customer,Job_Code,Material,     First_Weight, Second_Weight, Net_Weight, Unit_Price, Add_Charges, Deduction, Ticket_Amount,SOURCE, Destination,
                       OPERATOR, In_Time, PC)
VALUES (@Ticket_Type,
      @TicketNo,
      @VehicleNo,
      @nDate,
      @Customer,
      @Job_Code,
      @Material,
      @First_Weight,
      @Second_Weight,
      @Net_Weight,
      @Unit_Price,
      @Add_Charges,
      @Deduction,
      @Ticket_Amount,
      @Source,
      @Destination,
      @Operator,
      @In_Time,
      @PC)
 SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_Tickets')
 FROM tbl_Tickets
 UPDATE tbl_TicketNumber
 SET TicketNo = @TTicket,
  PC= @TPC,
  nDate= @TnDate WHERE (PC=@TPC) IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tbl_TicketNumber (TicketNo, PC, nDate)
 VALUES (@TTicket,
      @TPC,
      @TnDate) END END
SELECT *
FROM @tbl_ID
```

Then I change it to

```
cm.CommandText = " DECLARE @tbl_ID TABLE (nID int) UPDATE tbl_Tickets " & _
        " SET Ticket_Type = @Ticket_Type, TicketNo = @TicketNo, VehicleNo= @VehicleNo," & _
        " nDate=@nDate, Customer=@Customer, Job_Code=@Job_Code, Material=@Material, " & _
        " First_Weight=@First_Weight, Second_Weight=@Second_Weight, Net_Weight=@Net_Weight, " & _
        " Add_Charges=@Add_Charges, Deduction=@Deduction, Ticket_Amount=@Ticket_Amount, " & _
        " Source=@Source, Destination=@Destination, Operator=@Operator, Out_Time=@Out_Time, PC=@PC, Payment=@Payment,Unit_Price=@Unit_Price " & _
        EditString & _
        " OUTPUT INSERTED.QS_Code INTO @tbl_ID (nID)  WHERE (VehicleNo=@VehicleNo) AND (Second_Weight IS NULL) AND  (Ticket_Type <>'Weighbridge_VOID') AND  (Ticket_Type <>'Cash_VOID') " & _
       " IF @@ROWCOUNT=0  " & _
        " BEGIN " & _
            " INSERT INTO tbl_Tickets (Ticket_Type, TicketNo, VehicleNo, nDate, Customer,Job_Code,Material, " & _
            " First_Weight, Second_Weight, Net_Weight, Unit_Price, Add_Charges, Deduction, Ticket_Amount,Source, " & _
            " Destination, Operator, In_Time, PC, Payment " & _
            AddString & " ) VALUES (@Ticket_Type, '00-00', @VehicleNo, @nDate, @Customer,@Job_Code,@Material, " & _
            " @First_Weight, @Second_Weight, @Net_Weight, @Unit_Price, @Add_Charges, @Deduction, @Ticket_Amount,@Source, " & _
            " @Destination, @Operator, @In_Time, @PC, @Payment  " & _
            AddStringVal & " ) SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_Tickets') FROM tbl_Tickets " & _
           " END SELECT * From @tbl_ID" '
```

And add the TicketNumberUpdate sub after this update like this

```
cm.CommandText = " UPDATE tbl_TicketNumber " & _
            " SET TicketNo = @TTicket, PC= @TPC, nDate= @TnDate" & _
            " WHERE (PC=@TPC) " & _
           " IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 " & _
           " INSERT INTO tbl_TicketNumber (TicketNo, PC, nDate) VALUES (@TTicket,@TPC,@TnDate) "
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Can you format the code as it would appear in sql studio manager so that it is easier to read?

Comment: Ok  w0051977 can you see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're ignoring the value of the IDENT_CURRENT
Try changing

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_Tickets')
FROM tbl_Tickets

UPDATE tbl_TicketNumber SET
    TicketNo = @TTicket,
    PC= @TPC,
    nDate= @TnDate
WHERE (PC=@TPC)
```

to this

```
SET @TTicket = IDENT_CURRENT('tbl_Tickets')

UPDATE tbl_TicketNumber SET
    TicketNo = @TTicket,
    PC= @TPC,
    nDate= @TnDate
WHERE (PC=@TPC)
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply.. Im using ExecuteScalar for get this Identity  number for later use in vb, i cannot assign to @TTicket im passing other parameter to it, please check this also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844207/invoice-printing-wrong-data)