# 2.0 Application run on .net Framework 4.5.1

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

I have an application that created on VS 2010 and my project was compiled for targeting .Net FW 2.0 and now the problem is my application sometime misbehave on client machine, sometime it saves duplicate data and sometime it crashes. client machine running on .net Framework 4.5.1 is this root cause of these issues?

Can i uninstall this Framework 4.5.1 and install Old Framework?

Sry i was asking which framework is the best for application develop by Visual Studio 2010 Compile for Framework 2.0, can i use 4.0 ?

Comment: `What is the best framework version for this app 2, 3 or 4?` => We don't know the app, so this question cannot be answered ...

Comment: Sry i was asking which framework is the best for application develop by Visual Studio 2010 Compile for Framework 2.0

Comment: If it crashes, what kind of error doe you get? Are you sure that there isn't just a bug(s) hiding in your code?

Comment: Well Code is working fine when im testing and when im there with the client i didnt saw any issue but when rare occasion it happens, i mean some time 3 or 4 times a day, this app is running 12 hrs

Comment: Well without any errorinformation. I fear it is nearly impossible to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Most likely a but in your application, less likely to be a bug in .NET framework.

Comment: im sry thanks for the help any way, this what happen [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874001/sql-server-duplicates-value  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826343/webbrowser-control-printing-wrong-data